# How can we send a flash SMS with reply option?

Tags: sms, smpp

Normally if we send flash SMS through SMSC using SMPP protocol, it will directly display the message in the user handset, without storing in inbox.

There are only few option either Save/Discard or Exit, not Reply.

I would like to send the flash message such a way that user just reply to the message without storing the message.

To do this, what parameter need to be configured in the SMPP?

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765369/how-to-correctly-represent-message-class-in-smpp

Comment: This is not the duplicate, Since I am able to set the message class and receive flash message. But my question is how to get the reply option in the flash message.

Comment: Even I want to acheive the same functionality, I am able to send flash sms but wanted send with Yes or No option  , If Yes send ack msg or do nothing. If you are able to acheive please let me know.